# Are "way better" and "way more" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, slang, modifiers

"Way better" and "way more" are popular expressions, but they both seem incorrect to me. "Far better", "far more", "much better", and "much more" all seem correct. Is this true? If so, why?

Comment: What criterion would satisfy you that something is "correct"?

Comment: It is correct so long as my parents don't correct me, and they're in their 80's. Actually, I would consider slang as incorrect and informal to be marginal.

Comment: That’s a definition of correctness that has little to do with linguistic reality. Correctness is in large part a function of context. There are contexts in which slang is entirely appropriate and therefore correct. Indeed, there are contexts in which anything but slang is so stilted as to be pragmatically incorrect. The same goes for informal usages and, mutatis mutandis, for usages that Miss Thistlebottom at her strictest couldn’t fault.

Comment: I understand. The context I am looking for is formal to informal.

Comment: @xpda I would suggest asking your parents for their intuitions of what is correct if that is your criterion.

Comment: Ah... I should have thought of that.

Comment: I think this usage of "way" is fine, but if it seems incorrect to you just don't say it, you have other options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, "way" was a contraction of ["away"](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/03/way-down-yonder-in-etymology.html). It took on an adverbial meaning in the early 1900s:

> In the 19th century, “‘way” was also used for “away” in the sense of a great distance: “way towards Tupper’s Lake” (1849); “He sat ‘way under the mantle” (1888); “way below cost” (1890); “mere specks, ‘way down the road” (1927), and so on. (Note that some writers used an apostrophe to show the “a” had been dropped from “away.”)
>
> In addition, since the 19th century both “away” and “way” have been used as adverbs to add emphasis. These usages are heard chiefly in the US, the OED notes, though it includes some British citations.
>
> Here are some “away” citations: “away up in Canada” (1818); “away down east” (1825); “away back in 1840″ (1882); “away up in price” (1903); “away behind” (1906); “I’m away wrong” (1910); and “away down in the list” (1858).
>
> And here are some “way” citations: “way over yonder” (1850); “way down south” (1851); “way down East” (1854); “‘way down amongst the roots” (1866); and “sick of it way through” (1908).
>
> Finally, we come to the usage you’re talking about, and here’s where “way” and “away” part company. This is the adverbial use of “way” to mean “much” or “far.”

*Way* can be used as an adverb, but it is very informal. According to [this entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/way):

> — **adv**
>
> 1. *informal*
>      a. at a considerable distance or extent: way over yonder
>      b. very far: they're way up the mountain
> 2. *informal*  by far; considerably: way better
> 3. *slang*  truly; genuinely: they have a way cool site

It is not incorrect to say that something is *way better* or that you have *way more* of something, but it is not formal. It has also been in adverbial use for long enough that 80 year olds should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason "way more" or "way better" might **sound** incorrect is that the word "way" is also commonly used as a noun, as in "which way should I go?". You could substitute "which direction should I go?" for "which way should I go?" but heretofore I have not heard anyone say (even in slang) that something is a "direction cool site."  (I might bloody well have to eat my hat in the future but for now I haven't yet heard that instance of delightfully creative usage stretching enjoying the slang category of acceptability.)  If someone is associating the **noun** form of the word "way" in an adverbial context (just as a matter of familiarity or habit and not by way of linguistic analysis), then the ear might reject the usage based on the fact that something seems "incorrect" when a noun is substituted for an adverb.

That is how I determined why the slang use of the word "way" as in "way more help" was unpleasant sounding to me when I first heard it.  So while admittedly the ear can be deceiving and is no substitute for rigorous linguistic analysis, the ear as one of our 5 sense instruments does alert us to external stimuli that are different than what we are used to and therefore provides us with departure points for further investigation.

Comment: I find this suggestion very dubious. When an expression is widely used (as this one is, though much more in the US than the UK from my experience), the judgment of whether it sounds "incorrect" is a purely social one.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of North America, Way seems to have almost entirely replaced far (more), much (more), many (more) as it was hardly ever heard in Britain no so many years ago so it must be an Americanism that has gained currency because it can be substituted for the other three words. But it sounds terrible and I would never use it.